# Heroku server deployment, possible CORS issue

Tags: heroku, cors

I am having some trouble hitting my endpoints on my server that is deployed on Heroku. Front end is deployed on Github using gh-pages.

App link
https://cbied.github.io/face-recognition/

frontend
https://github.com/cbied/face-recognition

backend
https://github.com/cbied/face-recognition-api

It looks like a CORS issue because when I try to hit any endpoint (besides "/" (GET)) I get a CORS error. I have tried on Postman, I can use a get to get "/" end point to see if my server is up and running. When I hit that endpoint I get a response, most of the time. Trying any other endpoint like /signIn (POST) or /register (POST) will give me a CORS error and crash my app of the server.

Below are my Heroku logs, CORS error in console, and network tab for /register.

[Heroku Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w29gu.png)

[CORS error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uxl92.png)

[Network tab 503 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ziez0.png)

Let me know if I can provide any more information that would be helpful.
Thanks so much!

I am currently using cors@2.8.5 in my server. app.use(cors())
I have tried...
setting the headers to allow cors (with and without installing cors itself)
using mode:no-cors on my frontend even though that is not recommended
resetting my server on Heroku
rebuilding my frontend and backend
cors-anywhere (I got a separate issue with this)
and probably more that I can't think of bc I'm tired haha

**A little bit of an update...**
If I use the cors options below:

```
app.use(cors({
  origin: 'https://cbied.github.io',
  methods: ['GET','POST','DELETE','UPDATE','PUT','PATCH']
}))
```

I still get a CORS issue: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. But in the network tab, I get 503 service unavailable

**Update 09/24/2023**
Disregard the 503 error I mentioned before, I now know why this happens:

When an error is thrown, even if there is a .catch(), the server will go down. This is misleading since, using the CLI (heroku logs --tail), it says it changes from "crashed" to "up" again but you still get the 503 error. To fix this, go to the "Overview" of your server in Heroku, click the drop down menu that says "more, and click "Restart all dynos". This will restart your server so you can get back to your stupid cors issue. :)